# Intuition behind 'Family of Solutions'

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equations derived from simultaneous equations.

$x=\frac{2}{3-a}$

$y=\frac{3(1-a)}{1-a}$

For $a=3$ we get no solutions, which makes sense to me.

However, for $a=1$ my understanding is we get a family of solutions.

$x=1$

$y=\lambda$

What is the reasoning behind this?  Why do we not simply get no solutions?  I see that we are essentially dividing $0$ by $0$ but is this not still undefined?

Comment: How did you *get* to $y=\frac {3(1-a)}{1-a}$?  If you get to it by starting with $y(1-a) = 3(1-a)$ and dividing by $1-a$ the division was not allowed and the result (something undefined) is not legitimate.  Instead what you have is simply a statement $0*y = 3*y$ which is perfectly fine and has infinite solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the following equations ***DERIVED*** from simultaneous equations (emphasis mine)

which means you didn't *start* with $y = \frac {3(1-a)}{1-a}$ but that you arrived at the conclusion, probably from $y(1-a) =3(1-a)$.

Had you *started* with $y=\frac {3(1-a)}{1-a}$ then you'd be correct.  $a =1$ is impossible.  But if you start with $y(1-a) = 3(1-a)$ then $a = 1$ means $y*0 = 3*0$ which is perfectly fine.

If you divide both sides by an unknown you must do two things.  You must specify that the result you get from the dividing is conditional case that assumes what you are dividing by is not $0$. And you must consider the other conditional case that it *is* $0$ and we do *not* divide it.

SO you did *NOT* correctly derive that $y = \frac {3(1-a)}{1-a}$.  You derived that EITHER $a\ne 1$ and $y= \frac{3(1-a)}{1-a}$  OR that $y*0 = 3*0$.  The second is *not* a problem and has "a family of solutions".

Comment: Thank you!  I've always been a bit unsure with dividing by unknowns but this cleared it up.